# $\in$ : How to have it face down in MathJax

Tags: discussion, mathjax

How can I get a down-facing $\in$ symbol? I'd like to do this:

$$A =\underset{\underset{B}{\text{^}}}{0}$$

Here, I'd like the ^ to be $\in$ but rotated through an angle of $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

---

Comment:

This question is specifically about MathJax. I'd like to be able to ask a question in StackExchange using this symbolism if possible.

Comment: Hm, I was going to suggest [TeX site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) but the [questions tagged mathjax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax) have 50% closing rate there: 17 of 34.

Comment: @user79365 mathjax$\ne$TeX, it simply mimics the syntax.  As a crude example, it's a bit like painting a BMW to look like a Mercedes and then taking it to the Mercedes dealership for repair...sure, they can probably fix it, but it doesn't _really_ belong there.

Comment: @ScottH. Sure, it's TeX.SE users who define the scope of their site, not me. That's why I checked there first. The culture of Math.SE happens to be more inclusive; most of us do not say "Homework$\ne$Mathematics, it simply mimics the syntax". (Though it may be a correct statement.)

Comment: @user79365 I see the situations as being quite different.  Math homework quite clearly involves math, but mathjax in no way involves tex.  Obviously it would be more inclusive to allow questions that are currently considered off topic, as would also be the case here.

Comment: While the answers here have demonstrated that you *can* do that, I don't think you *should*. It's typographically awful.

Answer (score 10):

Using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), the closest I was able to find was `\pitchfork`:
$$
\Large\pitchfork
$$
Or you can play around like: `{\small\bigcap\lower{1.3pt}{\hspace{-8pt}\large|}}`
$$
{\small\bigcap\lower{1.3pt}{\hspace{-8pt}\large|}}
$$
However, I don't think there is a built-in character like that.

---

**Addendum:**

Motivated by "ELEMENT OF OPENING DOWNWARDS" : $\unicode{x2AD9}$ found by J.M., I found "ELEMENT OF OPENING UPWARDS" : $\unicode{x27D2}$

That is `\unicode{x27D2}`

Comment: 0.0 Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome with Windows XP and the symbol I see is an empty square !

Comment: An empty square indicates that no font installed in your system has that particular [Unicode codepoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

Answer (score 7):

$$A=\underset{\unicode{x2AD9}\atop B}{0}$$

That is,

```
A=\underset{\unicode{x2AD9}\atop B}{0}
```

Comment: Already beat you to [it](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412567/langle-v-t-dagger-v-rangle-oversetdef-langle-tv-v-rangle-zer). Oh, wait, yours is a bit more fancy.

Comment: Moral lesson: read carefully before making pronouncements.

Comment: Renders as an empty rectangle in my Chrome, so probably not a cross-browser solution.

Comment: @user, interesting. It's working on Firefox and Opera on my end; if you've other browsers, could you check?

Comment: Works in Firefox and IE (under Win7). At 100% the symbol is too small to be actually read, but this is probably browser-independent: the box that Chrome shows is also tiny.

Comment: Could be adjusted, tho: $A=\underset{{\displaystyle \unicode{x2AD9}} \atop B}{0}$

Comment: Nice. I hadn't looked through the unicode. (+1)

Comment: @user79365: If it shows as an empty rectangle, it is almost surely a font issue.

Comment: @user79365 I guess you should upgrade from Chrome to a modern browser.

Comment: It shows an empty rectangle on my screen - IE9 on Windows. robjohn's solution is very close to what OP wants.

Comment: An empty square indicates that no font installed in your system has that particular [Unicode codepoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).