# What latex packages are used this site?

Tags: support, mathjax

What are the TeX packages automatically imported in the math.stackexchange site? And is there a way to include different packages in the response box? I ask because I would like to use certain symbolic packages when writing questions, and couldn't figure out how to use the necessary packages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site uses [Mathjax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax), which is not exactly the same thing as TeX, although you can use LaTeX syntax and most of common things you know from LaTeX are available. See also this older post: [What is the relation between Latex and MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/what-is-the-relation-between-latex-and-mathjax/)

Here you can find list of symbols supported by MathJax: [Supported LaTeX commands](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands).

---

There were already some questions asked here on meta how to get some specific symbols, for example

- [Reverted diagonal dots](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/reverted-diagonal-dots)
- [$\in$ : How to have it face down in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9847/in-how-to-have-it-face-down-in-mathjax)
- [How do you render a closed surface double integral?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9973/how-do-you-render-a-closed-surface-double-integral)

So there is a chance that if you are missing some specific symbol, someone will be able to give you advice about that.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Martin!